# Efficiently find indices of all values in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a very large array, consisting of integers between 0 and N, where each value occurs at least once.

I'd like to know, for each value *k*, all the indices in my array where the array's value equals *k*.

For example:

```
arr = np.array([0,1,2,3,2,1,0])
desired_output = {
    0: np.array([0,6]),
    1: np.array([1,5]),
    2: np.array([2,4]),
    3: np.array([3]),
    }
```

Right now I am accomplishing this with a loop over `range(N+1)`, and calling `np.where` N times.

```
indices = {}
for value in range(max(arr)+1):
    indices[value] = np.where(arr == value)[0]
```

This loop is by far the slowest part of my code. (Both the `arr==value` evaluation and the `np.where` call take up significant chunks of time.) Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I also tried playing around with `np.unique(arr, return_index=True)` but that only tells me the very first index, rather than all of them.

Comment: You can iterate over unique items in the array instead of looping using range. Create a set out of the array and iterate over that set. It can reduce the overhead.

Comment: @nishparadox2 That's not going to do anything, because I already know what the unique values are: 0 through N, which you get more efficiently with a range than with a call to unique().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pythonic way is using `collections.defaultdict()`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> 
>>> for i, j in enumerate(arr):
...     d[j].append(i)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: [0, 6], 1: [1, 5], 2: [2, 4], 3: [3]})
```

And here is a Numpythonic way using a dictionary comprehension and `numpy.where()`:

```
>>> {i: np.where(arr == i)[0] for i in np.unique(arr)}
{0: array([0, 6]), 1: array([1, 5]), 2: array([2, 4]), 3: array([3])}
```

And here is a pure Numpythonic approach if you don't want to involve the dictionary:

```
>>> uniq = np.unique(arr)
>>> args, indices = np.where((np.tile(arr, len(uniq)).reshape(len(uniq), len(arr)) == np.vstack(uniq)))
>>> np.split(indices, np.where(np.diff(args))[0] + 1)
[array([0, 6]), array([1, 5]), array([2, 4]), array([3])]
```

Comment: My input array is rather large, so I'd expected this solution to be even slower than mine (considering it loops over all elements) but it turns out to be very fast. Considering it's simpler than the other answers, I'll accept this one.

Comment: Well this deserves an upvote too given it's simpler as OP stated! :)

Comment: @acdr I just gave this answer based on your expected output which is a dictionary, Check out the answer for only categorizing the indices in numpy.

Comment: @Divakar Forza KISS principal!

Answer (score 7):

**Approach #1**

Here's a vectorized approach to get those indices as list of arrays -

```
sidx = arr.argsort()
unq, cut_idx = np.unique(arr[sidx],return_index=True)
indices = np.split(sidx,cut_idx)[1:]
```

If you want the final dictionary that corresponds each unique element to their indices, finally we can use a loop-comprehension -

```
dict_out = {unq[i]:iterID for i,iterID in enumerate(indices)}
```

---

**Approach #2**

If you are just interested in the list of arrays, here's an alternative meant for performance -

```
sidx = arr.argsort()
indices = np.split(sidx,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(arr[sidx])>0)+1)
```

Comment: That is quite clever. I'll give this a try.

Comment: So this is about 6.5 times faster than the answer I actually accepted. Given that the cleverness does obfuscate what the purpose of the code is, I'll stick to the simpler solution, but it definitely deserves an upvote and some props. :)

Comment: @acdr I appreciate any feedback on runtimes, as I worry about that a lot. Thanks for bringing in those upvotes ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know numpy but you could definitely do this in one iteration, with a defaultdict:

```
indices = defaultdict(list)
for i, val in enumerate(arr):
    indices[val].append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully vectorized solution using the [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
k, idx = npi.groupy_by(arr, np.arange(len(arr)))
```

On a higher level; why do you need these indices? Subsequent grouped-operations can usually be computed much more efficiently using the group_by functionality [eg, npi.group_by(arr).mean(someotherarray)], without explicitly computing the indices of the keys.